# Cannot get "Buy X get Y free" working

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I am on Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

I am trying to get a promotion rule to work "Buy X get Y free"

Meaning if customer buy Item OW-1 , the customer will get item WL-1 free.  I tried many times having both products in my cart to test but is not working after creating promotional rules.

My rule is:

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
SKU  is  WL-1

Apply

Discount Amount *

Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To

Discount Qty Step (Buy X)

Apply to Shipping Amount

Free Shipping

Stop Further Rules Processing

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
SKU  is  OW-1

Answer (score 7):

Default Magento Buy X Get Y Free rule works only for one product. Means, if customer buy X="SKU-OW-1" customer will get free Y="SKU-OW-1". if you want to set another product as a Y then you need to create custom module for that. There are several free extensions available on Magento Connect that will do things for you.

This might help you to create rule: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes#buy_1_get_1

Comment: Thanks for this answer. So that's why mine wasn't working. Haha!

Comment: Note that if you can't see SKU as one of the attributes for your rule then you should go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes and edit the SKU to enable "Use for Promo Rule Conditions".

Comment: A much easier way is to use a third party module like the Special Promotions Pro from Amasty (https://goo.gl/9WxbA4). It really works with our needs.

Comment: Magento documentation no longer exists :-(