# Shopping Cart Rule - Buy 5 get one Free

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

I am trying to create a shopping cart rule, so far in the **Conditions** tab I have

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
```

If total quantity  equals or greater than  5  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
Category  is  686

In **Actions** I have **Buy x get Y Free** and I have the following options:

```
Discount Amount 1
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To 0
Discount Qty Step (Buy X) 5
Apply to Shipping Amount NO
Free Shipping NO
Stop Further Rules Processing NO
```

But I have tried adding the 5 items that match and I have a coupon I have entered the coupon, but it says invalid. I have also tried it without a coupon and it does not seem to add the free product.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60765/cannot-get-buy-x-get-y-free-working/60773 See this answer, Buy x get Y Free only works if a customer is buying the same product

Comment: I have tried it with 5 of the same product, but nothing appears to happen. I have tried the link example, and its still not working

Comment: Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To 0 should that be set to 1

Comment: tried that and its still not working im afraid. Is there anything in the System Config I need to change?